# How to center a button in footer in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to implement three `ion-button`'s in `ion-footer`, each algining to left, middle and right respectively.
It seems `ion-button`'s with `start` and `end` can do left and right.

How about middle? I have checked the API and ion component, it seems `ion-title` is by default centered, but there is no out-of-box way to get button in the middle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `ion-footer` element, try using `ion-grid` and then remove the padding from the grid.

```
<ion-footer>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row no-padding no-margin>
            <ion-col col-4 no-padding>
                <button ion-button full>Button 1</button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4 no-padding>
                <button ion-button full>Button 2</button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-4 no-padding>
                <button ion-button full>Button 3</button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: This solution seems more ionic without touching css, though it feels slightly an overkill to use grid for "center one button" mission.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `float-start` and `float-end` to the first and third button respectively. By making use of `float-[start|end]` instead of `float-[left|right]` your buttons will shift position with the app [direction](https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/rtl-support/)

**HTML:**

```
<ion-footer>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button ion-button float-start>Button1</button>
    <button ion-button>Button2</button>
    <button ion-button float-end>Button3</button>
  </div>
</ion-footer>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Added a wrapping `<div>` for the buttons and gave it the style `text-align: center;`, becasue I was experiencing weird animation behavior without the wrapping `<div>`.